# Laravel count nested many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-9

I feel this should be pretty straight forward, but I can't seem to find the answers online...

I'm working on a Laravel 9 API project and I have the below relationships:

1. **Projects** have many **Groups**
2. **Groups** have a many to many relationship with **Users** using a pivot table called **GroupUser**

What I'm trying to do is get the count of all **Users** associated with a specific **Project** through each group, but I just want them in one combined list. For example:

A **Project** has 2 **Groups**, each of which have 3 **Users**, so the output would be a 6 **Users**, and I don't care about the same user being included in both groups and counted twice.

I've tried using the below in the **Project** model:

```
public function users()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Group::class)
}
```

But this seems to only work if the **Group** -> **User** relationship is a hasMany, but its a belongsToMany because of the pivot table.

Ideally I want to be able to access the count in a resource like this:

`$project->users()->count()`

Any ideas how I would go about getting this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because Laravel doesn't solve a belongsToThrough relationship natively, someone has made a package to support the funcionality:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through

As you can see from the 713 stars on GitHub it is quite popular.

That way you can define nested `belongsTo` relationships - and it actually supports infinitely deep relationships

Comment: Thanks for the link, however from what I can see this only allows for belongsTo relationships, where as I have Projects has many Groups has many to many Users